# HTML header/sidebar layout without fixed dimensions

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm currently designing a website with a quite simple layout consisting of a header and a sidebar on the left, like so:

```
+--------------+
| Header       |
+---+----------+
| N | Page     |
| a | content  |
| v |          |
+---+----------+
```

There are hundreds of sites with a similar layout. However, they all seem to use fixed widths and heights for the sidebar and header, respectively – something I strongly dislike; why shouldn't my sidebar take up exactly as much space as it needs?

My current approach uses the following document structure:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <!-- Header -->
    </header>
    <div id="page">
      <nav id="mainNav">
        <!-- Navigation sidebar -->
      </nav>
      <div id="content">
        <!-- Content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

styled with

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: table
  width: 100%;
}

#page {
  display: table-row;
}

header {
  caption-side: top;
  display: table-caption;
}

nav#mainNav {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 0; /* to achieve minimum width */
}

#content {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Which comes close to what I want. The `<header>` is styled as a table-caption because it has to span the whole width (and also because it kinda makes sense). Now, I'd also like the layout to take up all of the available height. However, setting `height: 100%` on `#container` (the pseudo-table) makes the whole thing higher than the viewport, because the height excludes any captions.

Is there any way to achieve this rather trivial task without having to resort to manually setting heights and widths (and, accordingly, margins)?

Comment: Why can't you just let your content determine the height? Unfortunately, having an element simply take up the rest of the available height is rather complex.

Comment: @watson speaks the truth.  The layout you are proposing is very difficult to render in a non-jagged sense.  Either make the nav and the page content have the same styling so it "appears" they are the same height or revisit your design to come up with a more modern layout.